# Global variable changes value magically in C

Tags: c, global-variables

This will probably require some looking into, but my question is very simple:

Why is `numPassenger` always 0 in the `parentHandler2()` function?

```
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <wait.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <math.h>

int getRand()
{
  return (rand() % 5001);
}

//////////GLOBAL//////////

const int CAPACITY = 100;
const int MEMSIZE = 1024;

char* sharedmem;

pid_t pid;

int numPassenger;
int numTram;

//////////GLOBAL//////////

//handles SIGALRM, generates passengers, sends SIGUSR1
void parentHandler1()
{
    numPassenger = getRand();
    sprintf(sharedmem, "%d", numPassenger);
    kill(getpid(), SIGUSR1);
}

//handles SIGUSR1, calculates number of trams needed, sends SIGUSR2
void childHandler()
{
    double n = atoi(sharedmem);
    numTram = (ceil(n/100));
    sprintf(sharedmem, "%d", numTram);
    kill(pid, SIGUSR2);
}

//outputs
void parentHandler2()
{
    int n = atoi(sharedmem);
    printf("Passengers: %d, Trams: %d\n", numPassenger, n);
}

int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
    srand(time(0));

    key_t key;
    int shmemaddr;

    //shared memory
    key=ftok(argv[0],1);
    shmemaddr=shmget(key,MEMSIZE,IPC_CREAT|S_IRUSR|S_IWUSR);
    sharedmem = shmat(shmemaddr,NULL,0);

    pid = fork();
    if ( pid > 0 )
    {
        //timer
        struct itimerval timer;
        timer.it_value.tv_sec = 3; 
        timer.it_value.tv_usec = 0; 
        timer.it_interval.tv_sec = 3;
        timer.it_interval.tv_usec = 0;  
        setitimer (ITIMER_REAL, &timer, NULL);

        signal(SIGALRM, parentHandler1);
        signal(SIGUSR1, childHandler);
    }
    else if ( pid == 0 )
    {
        signal(SIGUSR2, parentHandler2);
    }

    //not so busy waiting
    while(1) sleep(1);

   return 0;
}
```

https://gist.github.com/4299915

Comment: did you try making your child process wait?

Comment: when you get into `parentHandler2`, `numPassenger` was never touched. What do you expect it to be?

Comment: What should it wait for? In both above functions, the `parentHandler1()` and `childHandler()`, the variable is appropriately set.

Comment: Why is it never touched? As far as i know, the function executes when `SIGUSR2` is fired.

Comment: are the functions even executed? try emitting SIGALRM by yourself

Comment: All three functions are executed, it just outputs 0.

Comment: did you try doing the same procedure with your sharedmemory inside the parent process right after you have created the memory? so basically without all the fork'ing

Comment: @xQuare How can i have a parent process without the forking?

Comment: yeah it should be "before all the forking"

Comment: StackOverflow Rule of Thumb #6: When a poster claims that something is magical, it isn't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fork creates a new copy of the current process. Global variables aren't shared between processes. The only memory that is shared between your two processes is the memory returned by `shmget`. The value of `numPassenger` is never set in the child process.

Comment: Oh yes, now i get it, Thank You! I need better planning.